# How to remove all the parts of a split RAR archive file using command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, archiving

I’m generally use a Debian based Linux distribution of some sort; either Debian 7.8 or Linux Mint 17. I have a split RAR file like this:

```
filename.rar
filename.r01
filename.r02
filename.r03
etc ...
```

Having extracted the archive using `dtrx` or `unrar`, I’d like to delete all the part files of the split archive using, preferably a single line.

At the moment I do `rm filename.r*`, which in general works well, however if the files are name like `rabbid.ranger.robot.r01` it can delete the extracted directory `rabbid.ranger.robot` as well.

So I’m looking for something a bit more robust.

Will accept a short script as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the number of `.r0*` files you have you could replace the `*` with a `?` this will remove files that have .r0 and 1 other character. So it will remove `rabbid.ranger.robot.r01` but not `rabbid.ranger.robot.r010`
Generally I would use it as such:

```
rm filename.r??
```

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have a split RAR with parts numbered up to 12 (i.e., `filename.r12` as your last file) and you want to be extra careful not to remove *any* other files. Assuming [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) is your shell [and you're using version 4 or higher](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60257/how-to-create-a-sequence-with-leading-zeroes-using-brace-expansion#comment83345_60259) (`bash --version` to check), you can create an explicit list of files easily with [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
rm filename.rar filename.r{01..12}
```

This will remove *only* those files: even files named `filename.rtf` (or `filename.r13`) will be spared. Depending on what other files you have (or might have) in the folder, this may or may not be preferable to [the usually quite good `.r??` way suggested by Devan](https://superuser.com/a/898200/105707).

Brace expansion, including numeric ranges, is a very old feature of several shells. But before version 4, bash did not support zero-padding (i.e., you want names like `filename.r05`, not `filename.r5`).

You can check first to see what filenames a brace expression will expand to:

```
$ echo filename.rar filename.r{01..12}
filename.rar filename.r01 filename.r02 filename.r03 filename.r04 filename.r05 filename.r06 filename.r07 filename.r08 filename.r09 filename.r10 filename.r11 filename.r12
```

(You can check expressions with `*` or `?` this way, too--just remember that what it expands to depends on what folder you're in when you run the command.)

Comment: Two very good answers, hard to choose between them.  I'll certainly be using this feature of bash as well.  I felt Devan's answer had the edge, although not to belittle this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command; from the working directory:

```
find . -type f -name "filename.*" -exec rm  {} \;
```

This searches only for files that match, directories are excluded. It may be a good idea to first test the command with `ls` rather than `rm` to make sure it’s returning the results you desire.

```
find . -type f -name "filename.*" -exec ls {} \;
```

Comment: But `rm` (without `-r`) *also* excludes directories. This `find` way has no advantage over `rm filename.r*`, which fswings is trying to improve upon. `rm filename.r*` deletes as much as the OP wants to delete (and possibly more); this method with `find` deletes at least as much as `rm filename.r*`, *and sometimes more* since `find` is recursive (i.e., it descends into subdirectories and deletes files there, and in *their* subdirectories, etc.). You could confine it to operating on the contents of `.` by adding `-maxdepth 1`, but it still wouldn't have any advantages over `rm filename.r*`.